# Android Wear Intent Filter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I'm trying to use a custom intent filter to call the android wear activity. (not sure this is the best idea?) However, after registering the intent filter on the wear application, and deploying the mobile application I get the error:

```
Applications have the same package name com.nybblemouse.datalayerdatamap:
    mobile, wear
```

Can anyone offer some advise?

*Background information:*

I'm developing an android wear application which is using the data layer API to allow a http connection to hit a simple API and show the response on the watch app.

I've used the data layer API to successfully ask the mobile app to make the call, and now want to call the activity on the watch to display the results.

Android Wear manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.nybblemouse.datalayerdatamap.MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

In my seperate listener service class (for the data layer api), after successful http response:

```
Intent chilliIntent = new Intent();
chilliIntent.setAction("com.nybblemouse.datalayerdatamap.MainActivity");
chilliIntent.putExtra("CHILLIS", "10");
startActivity(chilliIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive research, I've created a sample Android Studio project demonstrating how this can be achieved. In short, all network traffic needs to go through Android Wear API, namely the Message API or the Data Layer API. This is rumoured to change in the upcoming Google IO event on 2015/05/27 with support of native wifi on Wear devices.

The process to call an activity on the Wear device from the Mobile device is as follows (assuming you've chosen the Data Layer API):

1. Create a datamap of data required to send in the Intent.
2. Create a new Data Layer API object with appropriate callbacks
3. Using the Node API, either cycling through or nodes or broadcast to your selected node using the Data Layer API Sender method.
4. On the Wear device, implement a service Data Layer API class with the required callbacks
5. Using the OnDataChanged callback, listen for your send datamap, and extract data as needed
6. Start an activity from the OnDataChanged method using an intent as usual.

I've documented this very throughly with DFD's, slides and an example project. You can view them all on my Github project:

https://github.com/kirgy/fandos

This project was presented to the South West Mobile user group in Bristol, UK in May 2015:
http://www.meetup.com/swmobile/events/220749834/